# PersistentBag.toString() stackoverflow error while querying the result of HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am a beginner in `Hibernate` and was trying to implement one of the `HQL` queries

```
Query q= em.createQuery("select p from Person p join p.company c");
        List<Person> l = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println(l.get(0));
```

When I run the above code I get the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hibernate5.testing.onetomany.Person.toString(Person.java:71)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:527)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at hibernate5.testing.onetomany.Company.toString(Company.java:72)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
```

However when I comment out the `sysout` It runs as expected.As per the stack trace it seems to concern with the `toString` method but I am not sure what is the issue here. Below are the `POJOs` or the `entities`

**Person**

```
getters and setters


    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", company=" + company + "]";
}
```

**Company**

```
 getters and setters


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Company [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", persons=" + persons + "]";
        }
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: What is type of `persons` in Person class?

Comment: Typo, Corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You are facing the problem as `Person#toString` calls the `Company#toString` and `Company#toString` again calls the `Person#toSting`.*

So, what is happening is When Person#toString called it called the below toString definition:

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", company=" + company + "]";
}
```

Now can see that you have contaminated the company also that means your return statement actually becomes `"Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", company=" + company.toString() + "]";` . So, it calls the Company#toString() now look the implementaion of `Company#toString()` it contains `persons` object in string concatination.Which again calls `Person#toString()` , and its goes on still the method stack is overflow.

Answer (score 0):

remove all tostrings

`@data` also containe `@tostring`

it will work